# Python Aiogram, how can i get correct photo url?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

In aiogram, i use this `url = bot.get_file_url(message.photo[-1].file_id)`but it returns me
false url.

`https://api.telegram.org/file/bot1921126565:AAHW3TMM4irSpa9tg_FKJ0KSFr4C_3vSwb0/AgACAgIAAxkBAAIClGFzLRkvcvIUAsxLJdz_ogkcmMpJAAKKtzEbJMuYS3Dxs2WcrhtcAQADAgADeQADIQQ`

but in telegram Bot API, returns the correct URL:

```
https://api.telegram.org/file/bot1921126565:AAHW3TMM4irSpa9tg_FKJ0KSFr4C_3vSwb0/photos/file_41.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in first case you get `file_id` as answer on success uploading. then you should get `file_path` by `getFile` method and `file_id` parameter. finnaly will build direct link.

https://api.telegram.org/bot1921126565:AAHW3TMM4irSpa9tg_FKJ0KSFr4C_3vSwb0/getFile?file_id=AgACAgIAAxkBAAICnGFzwsx2gZpwYzF5FpSFNFSNn1CkAAI7tjEbhNqhS2srOJ26DZv0AQADAgADcwADIQQ

download:

https://api.telegram.org/file/bot1921126565:AAHW3TMM4irSpa9tg_FKJ0KSFr4C_3vSwb0/photos/file_52.jpg.

enjoy!